# Python & Pandas: counting time data in 2h increments

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group a bunch of timeseries data into 2 hour chunks. I am very new to this so please bear wth me. I think I can use Pandas for this based on previous research.

I've got a dataset (mytime) that looks like this:

```
['15:23', '14:41', '13:54', '07:13', '20:21', '13:15', '14:48', '12:06', '08:37', '06:32', '07:04', '14:20', '16:28',     
'06:49', '08:39', '09:15', '08:54', '05:37', '14:43', '06:20', '11:25', '11:05', '09:28', '14:05', '14:24', '15:30', 
'13:28', '16:55', '09:29', '17:44', '07:24', '09:37', '06:47', '14:35', '10:55', '22:29', '06:24', '09:25', '06:45', 
'23:49', '19:34', '01:31', '14:22', '13:58', '09:08', '05:11', '08:09', '08:52', '02:50', '12:51', '17:33', '07:07', 
'08:11', '10:06', '23:48', '22:27', '11:15', '15:09', '16:45', '20:42', '12:12', '07:08', '16:13', '20:40', '17:26', 
'18:57', '15:07', '09:19', '09:10', '09:17', '09:26', '14:18', '06:31', '14:13', '14:01', '08:57', '21:34']
```

I want to take this dataset and basically see an output like this:

```
0-2: 4
2-4: 7
4-6: 3
6-8: 3
8-10: 2
10-12: 5
12-14: 14
....etc
```

Here is a subset of my code

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mycount = Counter()
mytime = []
with open('temp_dates.csv') as csvfile2:
    readCSV2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
    incoming = []
    for row in readCSV2:
         readin = row[0]
         time = row[1]
         year, month, day = (int(x) for x in readin.split('-'))
         ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
         wkday = ans.strftime("%A")
         incoming.append([wkday,time])
         mycount[wkday] += 1
         mytime.append(time)
    with open('new_dates2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(incoming)
csvfile2.close()

for key,value in sorted(mycount.iteritems()):
    daylist = key, value
    print(daylist)

#print(mytime)
df = pd.DataFrame()
#print(df)
df.groupby([df['mytime'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='2H')])
```

I'm guessing my first problem is the data is not properly formatted for TimeGrouper to understand? Second, i'm probably missing something else that tells the dataframe what to look at? Any help would be appreciated.

By request a snippet of the original source CSV file is as follows (we are only talking about column 2 which is populated into 'mytime').

```
Sunday,14:35
Sunday,10:55
Friday,22:29
Friday,06:24
Thursday,09:25
Wednesday,06:45
```

Comment: This is a little confusing. Your first statement is that you've got a list of times, but the first bit of code is constructing dates from a csv. I'm guessing that the list `mytime` contains the data and only the last two rows are the actual problem?

Comment: please provide a sample reproducible data set in the orginal format (CSV)

Comment: mytime is what i'm trying to pull the data from - it is populated from a CSV file (row[1]). the list of data above is printed directly from mytime

Comment: @Justin, it's much easier to process your original data in `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format compared to list of strings, which you parsed. Beside that you did't state whether you want to group only by time ignoring date or not...

Comment: @MaxU - there is no date involved, just a day and a time. I just need to group times. Also, I posted a snippet of the original file in the question. Thanks!

Comment: How do you parse that __reproducible__ CSV using `year, month, day = (int(x) for x in readin.split('-'))` ?

Comment: @MaxU - that is in regard to column1 - which is converting a date into a day of week. We are only working with column2 in this case - time (in the format of HH:MM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [96]: mytime = ['15:23', '14:41', '13:54', '07:13', '20:21', '13:15', '14:48', '12:06', '08:37', '06:32', '07:04', '14:20', '16:28',
    ...:
    ...: '06:49', '08:39', '09:15', '08:54', '05:37', '14:43', '06:20', '11:25', '11:05', '09:28', '14:05', '14:24', '15:30',
    ...: '13:28', '16:55', '09:29', '17:44', '07:24', '09:37', '06:47', '14:35', '10:55', '22:29', '06:24', '09:25', '06:45',
    ...: '23:49', '19:34', '01:31', '14:22', '13:58', '09:08', '05:11', '08:09', '08:52', '02:50', '12:51', '17:33', '07:07',
    ...: '08:11', '10:06', '23:48', '22:27', '11:15', '15:09', '16:45', '20:42', '12:12', '07:08', '16:13', '20:40', '17:26',
    ...: '18:57', '15:07', '09:19', '09:10', '09:17', '09:26', '14:18', '06:31', '14:13', '14:01', '08:57', '21:34']

In [97]: s = pd.to_datetime(mytime).to_series()

In [98]: s
Out[98]:
2017-04-26 15:23:00   2017-04-26 15:23:00
2017-04-26 14:41:00   2017-04-26 14:41:00
2017-04-26 13:54:00   2017-04-26 13:54:00
2017-04-26 07:13:00   2017-04-26 07:13:00
2017-04-26 20:21:00   2017-04-26 20:21:00
2017-04-26 13:15:00   2017-04-26 13:15:00
2017-04-26 14:48:00   2017-04-26 14:48:00
2017-04-26 12:06:00   2017-04-26 12:06:00
2017-04-26 08:37:00   2017-04-26 08:37:00
2017-04-26 06:32:00   2017-04-26 06:32:00
                              ...
2017-04-26 09:19:00   2017-04-26 09:19:00
2017-04-26 09:10:00   2017-04-26 09:10:00
2017-04-26 09:17:00   2017-04-26 09:17:00
2017-04-26 09:26:00   2017-04-26 09:26:00
2017-04-26 14:18:00   2017-04-26 14:18:00
2017-04-26 06:31:00   2017-04-26 06:31:00
2017-04-26 14:13:00   2017-04-26 14:13:00
2017-04-26 14:01:00   2017-04-26 14:01:00
2017-04-26 08:57:00   2017-04-26 08:57:00
2017-04-26 21:34:00   2017-04-26 21:34:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [106]: s.groupby(pd.cut(s.dt.hour,
     ...:                  bins=np.arange(26, step=2),
     ...:                  right=False,
     ...:                  include_lowest=True)) \
     ...:  .size()
     ...:
Out[106]:
[0, 2)       1
[2, 4)       1
[4, 6)       2
[6, 8)      12
[8, 10)     17
[10, 12)     5
[12, 14)     7
[14, 16)    15
[16, 18)     7
[18, 20)     2
[20, 22)     4
[22, 24)     4
dtype: int64
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', parse_dates=[1], names=['date','time'])

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
        date                time
0     Sunday 2017-04-26 14:35:00
1     Sunday 2017-04-26 10:55:00
2     Friday 2017-04-26 22:29:00
3     Friday 2017-04-26 06:24:00
4   Thursday 2017-04-26 09:25:00
5  Wednesday 2017-04-26 06:45:00

In [59]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df.time.dt.hour, bins=np.arange(26, step=2), include_lowest=True)).size()
Out[59]:
time
[0, 2]      0
(2, 4]      0
(4, 6]      2
(6, 8]      0
(8, 10]     2
(10, 12]    0
(12, 14]    1
(14, 16]    0
(16, 18]    0
(18, 20]    0
(20, 22]    1
(22, 24]    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Max. So in my case I want to pull this directly from the mytime object. So can I just set the dataframe to something like df = pd.DataFrame(mytime) ?

Comment: @Justin, sure, you can do this (see UPDATE). But it's much easier and much more efficient to use Pandas for parsing your data... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i got, still struggling with sort, you'll see the output:

```
data = ['15:23', '14:41', '13:54', '07:13', '20:21', '13:15', '14:48', '12:06', '08:37', '06:32', '07:04', '14:20', '16:28',     
'06:49', '08:39', '09:15', '08:54', '05:37', '14:43', '06:20', '11:25', '11:05', '09:28', '14:05', '14:24', '15:30', 
'13:28', '16:55', '09:29', '17:44', '07:24', '09:37', '06:47', '14:35', '10:55', '22:29', '06:24', '09:25', '06:45', 
'23:49', '19:34', '01:31', '14:22', '13:58', '09:08', '05:11', '08:09', '08:52', '02:50', '12:51', '17:33', '07:07', 
'08:11', '10:06', '23:48', '22:27', '11:15', '15:09', '16:45', '20:42', '12:12', '07:08', '16:13', '20:40', '17:26', 
'18:57', '15:07', '09:19', '09:10', '09:17', '09:26', '14:18', '06:31', '14:13', '14:01', '08:57', '21:34']


import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'mytime': data})

df['mytime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mytime']).dt.floor('2H').dt.time
df['hour'] = df.mytime.apply(lambda x: str(x.hour) + '-' + str(x.hour +2)) 
df = df.groupby('hour').size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using numpy's histogram function:

```
import numpy as np
data = ['15:23', '14:41', '13:54', '07:13', '20:21', '13:15', '14:48', '12:06', '08:37', '06:32', '07:04', '14:20', '16:28','06:49', '08:39', '09:15','08:54', '05:37', '14:43', '06:20', '11:25', '11:05', '09:28', '14:05','14:24', '15:30', '13:28', '16:55', '09:29', '17:44', '07:24', '09:37','06:47', '14:35', '10:55', '22:29', '06:24', '09:25', '06:45', '23:49','19:34', '01:31', '14:22', '13:58', '09:08', '05:11', '08:09', '08:52','02:50', '12:51', '17:33', '07:07', '08:11', '10:06', '23:48', '22:27','11:15', '15:09', '16:45', '20:42', '12:12', '07:08', '16:13', '20:40','17:26', '18:57', '15:07', '09:19', '09:10', '09:17', '09:26', '14:18', '06:31', '14:13', '14:01', '08:57', '21:34']
time = [int(h) + int(m)/60 for h, m in (y.split(':') for y in data)]
bins = list(range(0, 26, 2))
counts, bins = np.histogram(time, bins)
dict(zip(bins, counts))
```

Result:

```
{0: 1,
 2: 1,
 4: 2,
 6: 12,
 8: 17,
 10: 5,
 12: 7,
 14: 15,
 16: 7,
 18: 2,
 20: 4,
 22: 4}
```

Comment: Thanks. So in my case can I just set "data = mytime" since the value of mytime is equal to your manual input ?